# mariadb high Disk IO and IO Wait

Tags: mysql, mariadb, disk-io

We have two mariadb servers Master and Slave each on PR and DR, We are observing high disk io above 90% and iowait some time above 20, when mariadb backup start at night iowait goes above 30 and system become unresponsive causing watch dog process timeout and restart mariadb. when running dd command
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/test2.img bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
it write data between 300 to 500 Kb/s, we have checked storage level as well but no issue found at storage level as same storage has been in used for other DB's (Oracle) and no such IO issues there. i need help to identify this issue.
following is server.cnf of mariadb

```
[mysqld]
symbolic_links = 0
local_infile = 0
basedir = /usr
datadir = /data/mdb_data
pid_file = /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid
log_error = /var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
bind-address = ::
port = 3306
userstat = 1
plugin-load-add = server_audit=server_audit.so
server_audit = FORCE_PLUS_PERMANENT
server_audit_logging = on
server_audit_events = CONNECT,QUERY_DCL,QUERY_DDL
server_audit_output_type = syslog
cracklib_password_check = off
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
lower_case_table_names = 1
character-set-server = utf8
init_connect = SET NAMES utf8
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
skip-name-resolve
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
max_connections = 3000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 58G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_log_file_size = 1024m
key_buffer_size = 16M
log-error = /var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
skip-external-locking
slow_query_log = on
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mariadb/slowSQLs.log
performance_schema = on
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
sync_binlog = 1
max_allowed_packet = 512m
slave_max_allowed_packet = 200m
innodb_read_io_threads = 32
innodb_write_io_threads = 32
innodb_io_capacity = 600
slave_parallel_threads = 50
slave_parallel_max_queued = 2097152
slave_parallel_mode = optimistic
rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled = 0
rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled = 1
rpl_semi_sync_master_wait_point = AFTER_SYNC
binlog_commit_wait_usec = 10000
binlog_commit_wait_count = 1
server_audit_excl_users = repl@b.c,maxscale
slave-skip-errors = 1062,1032

[mysqld_safe]
syslog

[mariadb]
server_id = 228575792
log_slave_updates = on
log-bin
log-basename = db2
report_host = db2
```

from top

```
KiB Mem : 74046272 total, 32528492 free, 26723664 used, 14794120 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 33554428 total, 31482364 free,  2072064 used. 33507036 avail Mem
```

Comment: Which mariadb verson? What about `iostat -n 5` output. Can you include output from /usr/share/bcc/tools/biolatency? To look at the data delay from fdatasync `bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_fdatasync { @start[args->fd] = nsecs; @fd = args->fd} tracepoint:syscalls:sys_exit_fdatasync { @us[ustack, @fd] = hist((nsecs - @start[@fd]) / 1000); delete(@start[@fd])  } ' -p  $(pidof mysqld)` with debug symbols of mariadb installed.

Comment: iostat -x 10 dev253-3    138.35  28753.39  34505.02    457.25     12.36     89.33      7.09     98.09

Comment: mariadb-10.3.17, above command is unable to run, [root@db2 ~]# bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_fdatasync { @start[args->fd] = nsecs; @fd = args->fd} tracepoint:syscalls:sys_exit_fdatasync { @us[ustack, @fd] = hist((nsecs - @start[@fd]) / 1000); delete(@start[@fd])  } ' -p  $(pidof mysqld)
-bash: bpftrace: command not found

Comment: Yes bpftrace is another package. Edit the question to show results - comments contain neither the space or readability. A link to `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`  output will also be enlightening.

Comment: Use `pt-query-digest` on the slowlog to find the "worst" query at about the time of the issue.  Looking at that query _may_ lead to a solution.

Comment: can you please provide more details on show global status output, what need to monitor from it ? when running pt-query-digest on slow server-slow.log receiving following `Can't locate Digest/MD5.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./pt-query-digest line 2492.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./pt-query-digest line 2492.`

Comment: show global status [link](https://www.dropbox.com/t/EupJtYhoma08Myy3)